# Automatically create an application to Google Play

Tags: android, continuous-integration, google-play, apk

Is there a way to create new application on Google Play and at the same time upload the first .apk, without using the web interface?

From what I found until now, the [Android Publisher](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) API allows to upload new versions for already published app, while I want to automatically generate a new application into the Google Play (that could further be released using Fastlane tools or Jenkins server).

Comment: I don´t think so, if you release your app for the first time, you have to do many settings. Put prices, images, accept the developer standards etc....

Comment: It would be awesome if there would be a tool that would let you do this automatically. Thank you for response, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came at a conclusion. There is no tool or library to automate this part. Instead it could be integrated a phantomjs driver (or other headless browsers) to automate this.